# Unexpected return type of vavr's Either in reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, vavr

There are two simple methods using vavr's Either.

```
public Either<String, Integer> testEither(int s) {
    if (s == 0)
        return Either.left("Wrong");
    return Either.right(s);
}

public Mono<Either<String, Integer>> testReactorEither(int s) {
    return Mono.just(s).filter(x -> x == 0).map(Either::right)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(Either.left("ERROR")));
}
```

The `testEither` works normally, but meanwhile,  the `testReactorEither` raises a compile error of "incompatible types" which says the provided return type of `reactor.core.publisher.Mono<io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>>` is incompatible with required return of `reactor.core.publisher.Mono<io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>`.

I'm afraid the problem is just because the method of `map(Either::right)` just defines the `Right` type of `Integer` but not do the `Left` type, and then the return type of the method is `Either<?, Integer>`. Then the question is how I can get the expected return type in this case?

[UPDATED]

As Hinse mentioned in his comment, the issue is related to the limitation of Java type inference, and some links I found for the problem is listed as follows:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511252

https://e.printstacktrace.blog/java-type-inference-generic-methods-chain-call/

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101

Comment: If you notice in the error, it's saying you are passing in an Object, versus the desired value of a String, make sure you are passing in the correct values

Comment: @beastlyCoder  I passed a string `"ERROR"` into the left of Either. A string object in fact is an Object, and the integer object also is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example seems to 'lose' the type information for the left side when the `map(Either::right)` is applied.

Adding some type 'hints' to the map method call should do the trick. So the testReactorEither will look like this:

```java
public Mono<Either<String, Integer>> testReactorEither(int s) {
    return Mono.just(s)
            .filter(x -> x == 0)
            .<Either<String, Integer>>map(Either::right)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(Either.left("ERROR")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and it works. However, when comparing with the `testEither` method, the compiler does also not know the type of `Right` when returning `Either.left("Wrong")`, but the type inference works perfectly in the case. Does it mean there are issues of type inference in `reactor`?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the topic of type inference. I don't think that it's reactor specific. My guess would be that it has to do with the fact that the type inference has to deal with two 'levels' of type inference. 
So type inference would have had similar issue if the `Either` was wrapped in, for example, a Vavr `Optional` instead of a `Mono`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clue, and it seems that the case is indeed a limitation of java type inference. I added some (useful) links in the question.